# IndexOutOfBoundsException with Spinner and setOnItemSelectedListener

Tags: android, spinner, android-arrayadapter, indexoutofboundsexception

i can't find out a bug causing a IndexOutOfBoundsException.

I set up a Spinner with a simple Arrayadapter. I'm adding File-Names from a Folder als Array to my ArrayAdapter. This already worked until now, when i resumed from another activity where i deleted one of the files.

Now it is throwing the exception everytime i start the app and I can't find out why it is crashing.

Here is my method setting up the Spinner:

```
private void setupSpinner(final Context ctx) {
        final Context context = ctx;
        navSpinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.nav_spinner);
        navSpinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, FileUtilities.getProjectNames());
        navSpinnerAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        navSpinner.setAdapter(navSpinnerAdapter);
        navSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                pdfView.recycle();
                String path = FileUtilities.PFAD_PROJEKTE+"/"+parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
                gewaehlteProjekte = new ArrayList<String>();
                gewaehlteProjekte.add(path);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
                editor.putInt(SettingsActivity.KEY_PREF_PROJECT, position);
                editor.commit();
                new updatePresentationFolder(context).execute();
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });
        if(sharedPref.contains(SettingsActivity.KEY_PREF_PROJECT)) {
            navSpinner.setSelection(sharedPref.getInt(SettingsActivity.KEY_PREF_PROJECT, 0));
        }
    }
```

And here my Stacktrace:

Only thing I found out is, that this happens in the line where i set the on item selected listener.

```
07-22 13:01:59.230    9733-9733/lp.german.bischofshofpresenter.app E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 3, size is 3
            at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:251)
            at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:304)
            at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getItem(ArrayAdapter.java:337)
            at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:390)
            at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:362)
            at android.widget.Spinner.makeAndAddView(Spinner.java:390)
            at android.widget.Spinner.layout(Spinner.java:341)
            at android.widget.Spinner.onLayout(Spinner.java:305)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11283)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4224)
            at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:925)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11283)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4224)
            at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:925)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11283)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4224)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:431)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11283)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4224)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1628)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1486)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1399)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11283)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4224)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:431)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11283)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4224)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1489)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2442)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Any help is appreciated ;)

Answer (score 0):

Was the last project selected when one of the files was deleted ? If so the previously selected index is now too big. You should check before using the value with `setDelection`. e.g. :

```
    if(sharedPref.contains(SettingsActivity.KEY_PREF_PROJECT)) {
        int selected = Math.min(navSpinnerAdapter.getCount() - 1, sharedPref.getInt(SettingsActivity.KEY_PREF_PROJECT, 0)
        navSpinner.setSelection(selected);
    }
```

Comment: might be that it was selected

Comment: you should protect the `setSelection` against old (invalid) values, the sample code is one possible way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are not saving 3 in your preferences?

Answer (score 0):

I've found there are two things you should look at when an `Adapter`'s `getView()` method is called with a position that's out of range. The first is any call you make to `setSelection()`. As @bwt mentioned in a comment, you should always check the value you're passing into `setSelection()`, to make sure that it's a valid index to the `Adapter`'s collection, i.e., >= 0 and < the size of the collection. In the case of this particular problem, that's exactly what's going on: there's no safeguard against a pref value that is out of sync with the current project list returned by `getProjectNames()`.

The other thing to check is your `getCount()` method, if you've overridden `getCount()`. While this doesn't apply to this particular issue, I feel it's worth mentioning that if you *do* override `getCount()`, make sure there's no way it could get out of sync with the `Adapter`'s data. This is particularly important if the `Adapter` is managing a dynamic data set.

One other comment that might be useful... if you check for a valid position parameter in your `getView()` method, don't handle an error case by returning `null`. That will just cause hard-to-track-down problems, such as a `NullPointerException` from `android.widget.Spinner.setUpChild()`.